# Jquery: how to find value of input box without the person submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to find the value of an input field without the person submitting at all (similar to how autocomplete reacts without you having to enter or hit submit). I tried .val() but that only works after the person submits.

Comment: try onchange() or keyup() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get the value right after onkeyup event!

```
$("#input").on('keyup', function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    alert(inputVal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)  for `.val()`:

> Get the **current** value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

It has no relation to the form getting submitted or not. You can use it in any context in javascript and it should work. So you should use it inside a suitable event handler for your case. Hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Im' using it in meteor, not sure why but just now I was logging the value, it would keep getting me "" until I hit enter. Anyway it works now, I used the answer above. thanks